# Multiple Forms in Razor Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, mvvm

I have a page with multiple forms.
Forms are implemented in partial view concept with multiple models.
All these models are called in a single razor page. Now what im facing is when i submit the first form my **ModelValidationState.Valid** is always returning false .
When checked its validating the input fields from other forms also.
How to validate only one Model ?

@ Karney

Im using Razor Pages.Dont have a controller for this

Pasting here the code you asked for with its Folder Structure

**Pages/Staff/Onboarding/Index.cshtml**

```
@page
@model Contractor_HRMS.Pages.Staff.Onboarding.IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Staff Onboarding";
    Layout = "~/Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h4>STAFF ONBOARDING</h4>
<hr />


<div id="wizard">
    <!-- Tabstrip -->
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
        <li role="presentation" class="nav-item active">
            <a href="#StaffDetails" role="tab" class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab">Staff Details</a>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation" class="nav-item">
            <a href="#Biodata" class="nav-link" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Biodata</a>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation" class="nav-item">
            <a href="#EduQualification" class="nav-link" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Educational Qualification</a>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation" class="nav-item">
            <a href="#Assets" class="nav-link" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Assets</a>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation" class="nav-item">
            <a href="#Others" class="nav-link" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Others</a>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation" class="nav-item">
            <a href="#AttachForms" class="nav-link" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Attachment Of Forms</a>
        </li>

    </ul>
    <!-- Tab panes -->
    <div class="tab-content">

        <!-- STAFF DETAILS -->
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="StaffDetails">
            <br />
            <form method="post" asp-page-handler="InsertStaffDetails">
                <partial name="_StaffDetails" />
                <div style="float:right">
                    <input type='submit' class='btn btn-success' value='Save' />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>

        <!-- BIODATA -->
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="Biodata">
            <br />
            <form method="post" asp-page-handler="InsertBioData">
                <partial name="_BioData" />
                <div style="float:right">
                    <input type='submit' class='btn btn-success' value='Save' />
                </div>
            </form>

        </div>

        <!-- EDUCATIONAL QUALIFICATION -->
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="EduQualification">
            <br />
            <form method="post" asp-page-handler="InsertEduDetails">
                <partial name="_EduQualification" />
                <div style="float:right">
                    <input type='submit' class='btn btn-success' value='Save' />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>

        <!-- ASSETS -->
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="Assets">
            <br />
            <partial name="_StaffAssets" />            
        </div>

        <!-- OTHERS -->
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="Others">
            <br />
            <form method="post">
                <partial name="_Others" />
                <div style="float:right;">
                    <input type='button' class='btn btn-success' value='Save' />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>

        <!-- ATTACHMENT OF FORMS -->
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="AttachForms">
            <br />
            <form method="post">
                <partial name="_AttachmentOfForms" />
                <div style="float:right;">
                    <input type='button' class='btn btn-success' value='Save' />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
       
    </div>
</div>


@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

**Pages/Staff/Onboarding/Index.cshtml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Contractor_HRMS.Data;
using Contractor_HRMS.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding;


namespace Contractor_HRMS.Pages.Staff.Onboarding
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public IndexModel(ApplicationDbContext applicationDbContext)
        {
            _context = applicationDbContext;
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public StaffDetails StaffDetails { get; set; }

        [BindProperty]
        public StaffBioData StaffBioData { get; set; }

        [BindProperty]
        public StaffEduDetails StaffEduDetails { get; set; }

        [BindProperty]
        public StaffAssets StaffAssets { get; set; }

        [BindProperty]
        public StaffOthers StaffOthers { get; set; }

        //---Type Of Employee ---//
        public SelectList ShowTypeOfEmployee { get; set; }

        //---Employment Type ----//        
        public SelectList ShowEmploymentType { get; set; }

        //---Location ----------//        
        public SelectList ContractorLocation { get; set; }

        //--- Department -------//        
        public SelectList DeptName { get; set; }

        //-------Employment Category --------//        
        public SelectList EmpCategories { get; set; }

        //---------Employment Status ---------//        
        public SelectList EmpStatus { get; set; }

        //------------Regular/Temporary ----------//       
        public SelectList RegularOrTemporary { get; set; }

        // ------------Incentive Plan ----------------//        
        public SelectList IncentivePlans { get; set; }

        //-----------Gender--------------------------//       
        public SelectList StaffGender { get; set; }

        //--------------Religion---------------------//        
        public SelectList StaffReligion { get; set; }

        
        //--------------WorkPass Type------------------//        
        public SelectList WorkpassTypeList { get; set; }

        //-----------Highest Qualification -------------------//        
        public SelectList Qualification { get; set; }

        //-----------Asset Name -------------------//        
        public SelectList ShowAssetName { get; set; }

        //----------------Othes--------------------------//
        public string[] status = new[] { "Yes", "No" };

        public void OnGet()
        {
            ShowTypeOfEmployee = new SelectList(_context.TypeOfEmployees, "TypeOfEmployee", "TypeOfEmployee");
            ShowEmploymentType = new SelectList(_context.EmploymentTypes, "EmploymentType", "EmploymentType");
            ContractorLocation = new SelectList(_context.Location.OrderBy(e => e.location), "location", "location");
            DeptName = new SelectList(_context.Department.OrderBy(e => e.DeptName), "DeptName", "DeptName");
            EmpCategories = new SelectList(_context.EmploymentCategory.OrderBy(e => e.EmpCategories), "EmpCategories", "EmpCategories");
            EmpStatus = new SelectList(_context.EmploymentStatus.OrderBy(e => e.EmpStatus), "EmpStatus", "EmpStatus");
            RegularOrTemporary = new SelectList(_context.RegTemp.OrderBy(e => e.RegularOrTemporary), "RegularOrTemporary", "RegularOrTemporary");
            IncentivePlans = new SelectList(_context.IncentivePlan, "IncentivePlans", "IncentivePlans");
            StaffGender = new SelectList(_context.Gender, "StaffGender", "StaffGender");
            StaffReligion = new SelectList(_context.Religion, "StaffReligion", "StaffReligion");
            
            WorkpassTypeList = new SelectList(_context.WorkpassType.OrderBy(e=>e.workpassType), "workpassType", "workpassType");
            Qualification = new SelectList(_context.HighestQual, "Qualfication", "Qualfication");
            ShowAssetName = new SelectList(_context.Assets, "assetname", "assetname");

        }

        

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostInsertStaffDetailsAsync()
        {
            ShowTypeOfEmployee = new SelectList(_context.TypeOfEmployees, "TypeOfEmployee", "TypeOfEmployee");
            ShowEmploymentType = new SelectList(_context.EmploymentTypes, "EmploymentType", "EmploymentType");
            DHLLocation = new SelectList(_context.Location.OrderBy(e => e.location), "location", "location");
            DeptName = new SelectList(_context.Department.OrderBy(e => e.DeptName), "DeptName", "DeptName");
            EmpCategories = new SelectList(_context.EmploymentCategory.OrderBy(e => e.EmpCategories), "EmpCategories", "EmpCategories");
            EmpStatus = new SelectList(_context.EmploymentStatus.OrderBy(e => e.EmpStatus), "EmpStatus", "EmpStatus");
            RegularOrTemporary = new SelectList(_context.RegTemp.OrderBy(e => e.RegularOrTemporary), "RegularOrTemporary", "RegularOrTemporary");
            IncentivePlans = new SelectList(_context.IncentivePlan, "IncentivePlans", "IncentivePlans");
            
            
            if (ModelState.GetFieldValidationState("StaffDetails") == ModelValidationState.Valid)
            {
                await _context.StaffDetails.AddAsync(StaffDetails);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return Page();
            }
            else
            {
                var errors = ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors);
                return Page();
            }
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostInsertBioDataAsync()
        {
            StaffGender = new SelectList(_context.Gender, "StaffGender", "StaffGender");
            StaffReligion = new SelectList(_context.Religion, "StaffReligion", "StaffReligion");
            
            WorkpassTypeList = new SelectList(_context.WorkpassType.OrderBy(e => e.workpassType), "workpassType", "workpassType");

            
            if (ModelState.GetFieldValidationState("StaffBioData") == ModelValidationState.Valid)
            {
                await _context.StaffBioData.AddAsync(StaffBioData);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return Page();
            }
            else
            {
                return Page();
            }
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostInsertEduDetailsAsync()
        {
            Qualification = new SelectList(_context.HighestQual, "Qualfication", "Qualfication");

            if (ModelState.GetFieldValidationState("StaffEduDetails") == ModelValidationState.Valid)
            {
                await _context.StaffEduDetails.AddAsync(StaffEduDetails);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return Page();
            }
            else
            {
                return Page();
            }
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostInsertAssetsDetailsAsync()
        {
            ShowAssetName = new SelectList(_context.Assets, "assetname", "assetname");

            if (ModelState.GetFieldValidationState("StaffAssets") == ModelValidationState.Valid)
            {
                await _context.StaffAssets.AddAsync(StaffAssets);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return Page();
            }
            else
            {
                return Page();
            }
        }

        
    }
}
```

Partial View for StaffDetails **Pages/Staff/Onboarding/_StaffDetails.cshtml**

```
    @model Contractor_HRMS.Pages.Staff.Onboarding.IndexModel
@*
    For more information on enabling MVC for empty projects, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=397860
*@
    <div class="row">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <!-- Type Of Employee -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="StaffDetails.TypeOfEmployee" class="control-label-staff"></label>
                <select asp-for="StaffDetails.TypeOfEmployee" asp-items="Model.ShowTypeOfEmployee" class="form-control-staff">
                    <option value="">Please Select</option>
                </select><br/>
                <span asp-validation-for="StaffDetails.TypeOfEmployee" class="text-danger" style="margin-left:210px;"></span>
            </div>

            <!-- Employment Type -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="StaffDetails.EmploymentType" class="control-label-staff"></label>
                <select asp-for="StaffDetails.EmploymentType" asp-items="Model.ShowEmploymentType" class="form-control-staff">
                    <option value="">Please Select</option>
                </select><br/>
                <span asp-validation-for="StaffDetails.EmploymentType" class="text-danger" style="margin-left:210px;"></span>
            </div>

            <!-- Employee Id -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="StaffDetails.EmpID" class="control-label-staff"></label>
                <input asp-for="StaffDetails.EmpID" class="form-control-staff" /><br />
                <span asp-validation-for="StaffDetails.EmpID" class="text-danger" style="margin-left:210px;"></span>
            </div>

            <!-- Global Id -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="StaffDetails.GlobalId" class="control-label-staff"></label>
                <input asp-for="StaffDetails.GlobalId" class="form-control-staff" /><br />
                <span asp-validation-for="StaffDetails.GlobalId" class="text-danger" style="margin-left:210px;"></span>
            </div>

            <!-- Employee First Name(Preferred) -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="StaffDetails.PreferredEmpFname" class="control-label-staff"></label>
                <input asp-for="StaffDetails.PreferredEmpFname" class="form-control-staff" /><br />
                <span asp-validation-for="StaffDetails.PreferredEmpFname" class="text-danger" style="margin-left:210px;"></span>
            </div>

            <!-- Employee Last Name(Preferred) -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="StaffDetails.PreferredEmpLname" class="control-label-staff"></label>
                <input asp-for="StaffDetails.PreferredEmpLname" class="form-control-staff" /><br />
                <span asp-validation-for="StaffDetails.PreferredEmpLname" class="text-danger" style="margin-left:210px;"></span>
            </div>

            <!-- Location -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="StaffDetails.Location" class="control-label-staff"></label>
                <select asp-for="StaffDetails.Location" asp-items="Model.ContractorLocation" class="form-control-staff">
                    <option value="">Please Select</option>
                </select><br />
                <span asp-validation-for="StaffDetails.Location" class="text-danger" style="margin-left:210px;"></span>
            </div>

            <!-- Department -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="StaffDetails.Department" class="control-label-staff"></label>
                <select asp-for="StaffDetails.Department" asp-items="Model.DeptName" class="form-control-staff">
                    <option value="">Please Select</option>
                </select><br />
                <span asp-validation-for="StaffDetails.Department" class="text-danger" style="margin-left:210px;"></span>
            </div>

            <!-- Section -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="StaffDetails.Section" class="control-label-staff"></label>
                <input asp-for="StaffDetails.Section" class="form-control-staff" /><br />
                <span asp-validation-for="StaffDetails.Section" class="text-danger" style="margin-left:210px;"></span>
            </div>

            <!-- Job-Title -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="StaffDetails.JobTitle" class="control-label-staff"></label>
                <input asp-for="StaffDetails.JobTitle" class="form-control-staff" /><br />
                <span asp-validation-for="StaffDetails.JobTitle" class="text-danger" style="margin-left:210px;"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <!-- Cost-Center -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="StaffDetails.CostCentre" class="control-label-staff"></label>
                <input asp-for="StaffDetails.CostCentre" class="form-control-staff" /><br />
                <span asp-validation-for="StaffDetails.CostCentre" class="text-danger" style="margin-left:210px;"></span>
            </div>

            <!-- Employment-Category -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="StaffDetails.EmploymentCategory" class="control-label-staff"></label>
                <select asp-for="StaffDetails.EmploymentCategory" asp-items="Model.EmpCategories" class="form-control-staff">
                    <option value="">Please Select</option>
                </select><br />
                <span asp-validation-for="StaffDetails.EmploymentCategory" class="text-danger" style="margin-left:210px;"></span>
            </div>

            <!-- Contractor/Agency Name -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="StaffDetails.ContractorAgencyName" class="control-label-staff"></label>
                <input asp-for="StaffDetails.ContractorAgencyName" class="form-control-staff" /><br />
                <span asp-validation-for="StaffDetails.ContractorAgencyName" class="text-danger" style="margin-left:210px;"></span>
            </div>

            <!-- Start Date -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="StaffDetails.Startdate" class="control-label-staff"></label>
                <input asp-format="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" asp-for="StaffDetails.Startdate" class="form-control-staff" /><br />
                <span asp-validation-for="StaffDetails.Startdate" class="text-danger" style="margin-left:210px;"></span>
            </div>

            <!-- Supervisor Name -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="StaffDetails.SupervisorName" class="control-label-staff"></label>
                <input asp-for="StaffDetails.SupervisorName" class="form-control-staff" /><br />
                <span asp-validation-for="StaffDetails.SupervisorName" class="text-danger" style="margin-left:210px;"></span>
            </div>

            <!-- Compensation -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="StaffDetails.Compensation" class="control-label-staff"></label>
                <input asp-for="StaffDetails.Compensation" class="form-control-staff" /><br />
                <span asp-validation-for="StaffDetails.Compensation" class="text-danger" style="margin-left:210px;"></span>
            </div>

            <!-- Employment Status -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="StaffDetails.EmploymentStatus" class="control-label-staff"></label>
                <select asp-for="StaffDetails.EmploymentStatus" asp-items="Model.EmpStatus" class="form-control-staff">
                    <option value="">Please Select</option>
                </select><br />
                <span asp-validation-for="StaffDetails.EmploymentStatus" class="text-danger" style="margin-left:210px;"></span>
            </div>

            <!-- Regular/Temporary -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="StaffDetails.RegularTemp" class="control-label-staff"></label>
                <select asp-for="StaffDetails.RegularTemp" asp-items="Model.RegularOrTemporary" class="form-control-staff">
                    <option value="">Please Select</option>
                </select><br />
                <span asp-validation-for="StaffDetails.RegularTemp" class="text-danger" style="margin-left:210px;"></span>
            </div>

            <!-- Incentive Plan -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="StaffDetails.IncentivePlan" class="control-label-staff"></label>
                <select asp-for="StaffDetails.IncentivePlan" asp-items="Model.IncentivePlans" class="form-control-staff">
                    <option value="">Please Select</option>
                </select><br />
                <span asp-validation-for="StaffDetails.IncentivePlan" class="text-danger" style="margin-left:210px;"></span>
            </div>

            <!-- Target Incentive -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="StaffDetails.TargetIncentive" class="control-label-staff"></label>
                <input asp-for="StaffDetails.TargetIncentive" class="form-control-staff" /><br />
                <span asp-validation-for="StaffDetails.IncentivePlan" class="text-danger" style="margin-left:210px;"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group" style="display:none;">
                <label asp-for="StaffDetails.LastModifiedBy" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="StaffDetails.LastModifiedBy" class="form-control" value="jteena" />
                <span asp-validation-for="StaffDetails.LastModifiedBy" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" style="display:none;">
                <label asp-for="StaffDetails.LastModifiedTimestamp" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="StaffDetails.LastModifiedTimestamp" class="form-control" value="@DateTime.Now"/>
                <span asp-validation-for="StaffDetails.LastModifiedTimestamp" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Models/StaffDetails.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Contractor_HRMS.Models
{
    public class StaffDetails
    {
        //--- Staff Id ---//
        [Key]
        public int StaffID { get; set; }

        //--- Emp Id ---//      
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter Employee ID")]
        [Display(Name = "Employee ID*"),StringLength(100)]
        //[PageRemote(PageHandler = "IsEmployeeIDUse", HttpMethod = "get")]
        public string EmpID { get; set; }

        //--- Global Id ---//
        [Display(Name = "Global ID"), StringLength(50)]
        public string GlobalId { get; set; }

        //--Type of Employee ---//
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select Type Of Employee")]
        [Display(Name = "Type Of Employee*"),StringLength(100)]
        public string TypeOfEmployee { get; set; }

        //--Employment Type ---//
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select Employment Type")]
        [Display(Name = "Employment Type*"), StringLength(100)]
        public string EmploymentType { get; set; }

        //--Employment Category ---//
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select Employment Category")]
        [Display(Name = "Employment Category*"), StringLength(50)]
        public string EmploymentCategory { get; set; }

        //--Employment Status ---//
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select Employment Status")]
        [Display(Name = "Employment Status*"), StringLength(50)]
        public string EmploymentStatus { get; set; }

        //--Regular/Temporary ---//
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select Regular/Temporary")]
        [Display(Name = "Regular/Temporary*"), StringLength(50)]
        public string RegularTemp { get; set; }

        //--Preferred Employee First Name ---//
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter Employee First Name(Preferred)")]
        [Display(Name = "Employee First Name(Preferred)*"), StringLength(100)]
        public string PreferredEmpFname { get; set; }

        //--Preferred Employee Last Name ---//
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter Employee Last Name(Preferred)")]
        [Display(Name = "Employee Last Name(Preferred)*"), StringLength(100)]
        public string PreferredEmpLname { get; set; }

        //--Location ---//
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select Location")]
        [Display(Name = "Location*"), StringLength(100)]
        public string Location { get; set; }

        //--Department ---//
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter Department")]
        [Display(Name = "Department*"), StringLength(100)]
        public string Department { get; set; }

        //--Section ---//
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter Section")]
        [Display(Name = "Section*"), StringLength(100)]
        public string Section { get; set; }

        //--JobTitle ---//
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter JobTitle")]
        [Display(Name = "JobTitle*"), StringLength(100)]
        public string JobTitle { get; set; }

        //--Cost Center ---//
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter Cost Centre")]
        [Display(Name = "Cost Centre*"), StringLength(100)]
        public string CostCentre { get; set; }

        //--Contractor Agency Name ---//
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter Contractor Agency Name")]
        [Display(Name = "Contractor Agency Name*"), StringLength(255)]
        public string ContractorAgencyName { get; set; }

        //--Start Date ---//
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select Start Date")]
        [Display(Name = "Start Date*")]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime Startdate { get; set; }

        //--Supervisor Name ---//
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter Supervisor Name")]
        [Display(Name = "Supervisor Name*"), StringLength(255)]
        public string SupervisorName { get; set; }

        //--Supervisor Email ---//
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter Supervisor Email")]
        [Display(Name = "Supervisor Email*"), StringLength(255)]
        public string SupervisorEmail { get; set; }

        //--Compensation ---//
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter Compensation")]
        [Display(Name = "Compensation*"), StringLength(50)]
        public string Compensation { get; set; }

        //--Incentive Plan ---//
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select Incentive Plan")]
        [Display(Name = "Incentive Plan*"), StringLength(50)]
        public string IncentivePlan { get; set; }

        //--Target Incentive ---//
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter Target Incentive")]
        [Display(Name = "Target Incentive*"), StringLength(50)]
        public string TargetIncentive { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Last Modified By")]
        public string LastModifiedBy { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Last Modified TimeStamp")]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime LastModifiedTimestamp { get; set; }
        

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your controller and partial view's forms?

Comment: @Karney i have edited my question.Please check .Thanks

Comment: I have found the problem, please check it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the process of passing parameters from the view to the pagemodel, this property `LastModifiedTimestamp` is null, even though it is assigned. It is not be assigned correctly. Because **DateTime** generate this html code `<input type="datetime-local" />`.

A better solution is to change its type.

```
 <input asp-for="StaffDetails.LastModifiedTimestamp" class="form-control" type="datetime"  value="@DateTime.Now"/>
```

This is the `SupervisorEmail` need to be added.

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="StaffDetails.SupervisorEmail" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="StaffDetails.SupervisorEmail" class="form-control" value="" />
        <span asp-validation-for="StaffDetails.SupervisorEmail" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
```

Comment: This was not problem. I figured it out.Missed out one field in my design 'Supervisor Email'.Thats why it was not validating though.Thanks for your support

Comment: @Teena  Yes, I tested before and found that you didn't add this, but later found that there are still problems after adding it, which is caused by `LastModifiedTimestamp`. But I forgot to write it in the answer.

Comment: @Teena But I still hope you accept this answer. Because it will encourage me to help solve more problems.